# Determining the actual rotation axis direction after a rotation

Tags: rotations, python

I have two lines represented as 3D vectors with their individual start and end points. The red line is fixed on a base (`RV-O`, red vector origin) and can perform a full rotation between `0°` and `360°` in anticlockwise `z` direction . After a rotation about its origin using a given direction vector and angle, its end point `RV-E` becomes the new position `RV-E'`.

The orange line is connected on its origin point `OV-O` with the `RV-E'` and every rotation applied on the `RV-E` rotates it also in the same direction. Afterwards, it can independently rotate in `y` direction between `-90°` and `90°`and becomes the new position then `OV-E'`, as shown on the left side.

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50q9h.png)

If I apply a `~70°` rotation as shown on the middle `(Rotation of RV-E)` on the red line `RV-E`, the new positions of the red `RV-E'` and orange line `OV-E'` are fully correct.

But my problem begins after that. The applied rotation on the `OV-E'` in `y` direction to become a new `OV-E''` brings the line in a correct direction indeed, but with some offset `OV offset-E''`.

I implemented this in python. The 3D rotation matrix that I use looks like follows:

```
def rotate_line(self, axis_direction, origin, point_to_rotate, angle):

    angle = np.radians(angle)
    a, b, c = origin
    x, y, z = point_to_rotate


    if axis_direction == 0:
        u, v, w = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0] # Rotate in x direction
    elif axis_direction == 1:
        u, v, w = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]  # Rotate in y direction
    elif axis_direction == 2:
        u, v, w = [-0.1027, -0.1525, 0.9829] # Rotate in z direction

    cos = np.cos(angle)
    sin = np.sin(angle)
    qx = (a*(v**2 + w**2) -u*(b*v + c*w - u*x - v*y - w*z)) * (1-cos) + x*cos + (-c*v + b*w - w*y + v*z) * sin
    qy = (b*(u**2 + w**2) -v*(a*u + c*w - u*x - v*y - w*z)) * (1-cos) + y*cos + (c*u - a*w + w*x - u*z) * sin
    qz = (c*(u**2 + v**2) -w*(a*u + b*v - u*x - v*y - w*z)) * (1-cos) + z*cos + (-b*u + a*v - v*x + u*y) * sin

    return qx, qy, qz
```

I guess my problem is with the directions. I know the exact direction unit vector of the base. Therefore I can apply it for the rotations in `z` direction. But for rotations in `x` and `y` directions, I simply set `u, v, w = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]` and `u, v, w = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]`  which probably causes these offsets. My second problem is the shifted axes after applied rotations on a line. At the begin e.g. the `y` axis is on its default position, after rotation    it changes based on the new position of the line. Therefore my `if` conditions `if axis_direction ==` does not correct anymore for another planned rotation.

I would appreciate any help

**Edit:** Some code is added

```
self.red_line_rot_axis = 2 # rotation direction, z axis
self.orange_line_rot_axis = 1 # rotation direction, y axis

def visualize_red_line(self):
    self.red_line_origin = [-11.833, -173.2017, 1064.0267]

    self.red_line = vtk.vtkLineSource()
    self.red_line.SetPoint1(origin[0], origin[1], origin[2])
    self.red_line.SetPoint2(self.red_line.GetPoint1()[0], 
    self.red_line.GetPoint1()[1] + 40, self.red_line.GetPoint1()[2])
    self.red_line_origin = self.red_line.GetPoint1()
    self.red_line_curr_pos = self.red_line.GetPoint2()

    self.red_line_mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()   
    self.red_line_mapper.SetInputConnection(
    self.red_line.GetOutputPort())

    self.red_line_actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    self.red_line_actor.SetMapper(self.red_line_mapper)
    self.red_line_actor.GetProperty().SetColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    self.red_line_actor.GetProperty().SetLineWidth(2)

    self.renderer.AddActor(self.red_line_actor)


def visualize_orange_line(self):
    self.orange_line = vtk.vtkLineSource()
    self.orange_line.SetPoint1(self.red_line_curr_pos)
    self.orange_line.SetPoint2(self.red_line_curr_pos[0], 
    self.red_line_curr_pos[1] + 50, self.red_line_curr_pos[2])

    self.orange_line_origin = self.orange_line.GetPoint1()
    self.orange_line_curr_pos = self.orange_line.GetPoint2()

    self.orange_line_mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    self.orange_line_mapper.SetInputConnection(
    self.orange_line.GetOutputPort())

    self.orange_line_actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    self.orange_line_actor.SetMapper(self.orange_line_mapper)
    self.orange_line_actor.GetProperty().SetColor(0.9, 0.6, 0.1)
    self.orange_line_actor.GetProperty().SetLineWidth(2)

    self.renderer.AddActor(self.orange_line_actor)

    # Begin with the rotation after representing both lines
    rotate_red_line(self)



# Rotate red and orange line between 0° and x° with 1° increment each time about the origin of red line
def rotate_red_line(self):
    min_angle = 0.0
    max_angle = 50.0  #260 #360
    curr_angle = 1
    for idx in np.arange(min_angle, max_angle, curr_angle):
        rotated_red_line_pos = np.array(rotate_line(self, self.red_line_rot_axis,  self.red_line_origin , self.red_line_curr_pos, curr_angle))
        rotated_orange_line_pos = np.array(rotate_line(self, self.red_line_rot_axis,  self.red_line_origin , self.orange_line_curr_pos, curr_angle))

    # Visualize the rotation
    update_red_line_pos(self, rotated_red_line_pos, rotated_orange_line_pos)

    if curr_angle == max_angle:
        # Rotate the orange line afterwards
        rotate_orange_line(self, rotated_red_line_pos, rotated_orange_line_pos)

    curr_angle = np.round(curr_angle + 1, 2)

# Update the positions of the lines after rotation
def update_red_line_pos(self, rotated_red_line_pos, rotated_orange_line_pos,):

    self.red_line.SetPoint2(rotated_red_line_pos)

    self.orange_line.SetPoint1(rotated_red_line_pos)
    self.orange_line.SetPoint2(rotated_orange_line_pos)


# Rotate orange line between -20° and x° with 1° increment each time about the origin of orange line
# The origin of the orange line is the new position of the red line
def rotate_orange_line(self, rotated_red_line_pos, rotated_orange_line_pos):
    min_angle = -20.0
    max_angle = 180.0
    curr_angle = 1
    for idx in np.arange(min_angle, max_angle, curr_angle):
    rotated_orange_line_pos = np.array(rotate_line(self, self.orange_line_rot_axis,  rotated_red_line_pos , rotated_orange_line_pos, curr_angle))

        # Visualize the rotation
        update_orange_line_pos(self, rotated_orange_line_pos)

        curr_angle = np.round(curr_angle + 1, 2)

# Update the position of the orange line after rotation
def update_orange_line_pos(self, rotated_orange_line_pos):

self.orange_line.SetPoint2(rotated_orange_line_pos)
```

Answer (score 1):

The image of rotation of a point $E$ about an axis that passes through point $O$

is given by

$E' = O + R (E - O) = (I - R) O + R E $

If the unit vector of the axis is a = (u, v, w) as in your code, then

$R = a a^T + (I - a a^T) \cos \theta + S_a \sin \theta $

where

$S_a = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && - w && v \\ w && 0 && -u \\ -v && u && 0 \end{bmatrix}$

As per our discussion on the MSE chat, I realized that you want to rotate both line segment (the red and the orange) about the 'z' axis (which is not really the z axis, but an arbitrary axis), and then you want rotate only the orange line segment about the rotated Y axis resulting after rotation about your arbitrary 'z' axis.  You mentioned that you don't have any problems with the first rotation,  and that the problem is with the second rotation.  I am going to re-label the endpoints of the red segment as $A$ and $B$ respectively, and the orange segment as $B$ and $C$, (Because the origin of the orange segment is the end of the red segment).   After the first rotation, the images are

$\large A' = A + R_z (A - A) = A $

$\large B' = A + R_z (B - A ) $

$\large C' = A + R_z (C - A) $

Now for the second rotation, which is about the rotated $Y$ axis passing though the point $B'$

$\large B''  = B' + R_{y'} (B' - B') = B' $

$\large C'' = B' + R_{y'} (C' - B') = B' + R_{y'} R_z (C - B) $

Once can either calculate the axis $y'$ by rotating the $y$ axis about the $z$ axis, or make use of the fact that

$\large R_{y'} R_z = \left( R_z R_y R_z^T \right) R_z = R_z R_y $

Hence,

$\large C'' = B' + R_z R_y ( C - B ) = A + R_z (B - A) + R_z R_y (C - B ) $

Make sure, when implementing the rotations, that you correctly specify the point where the axis of rotation passes.

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand your answer. I have no problem with the rotation itself, but with the shift of axes after the first rotation.

Comment: You should apply the first rotation to both vectors, then the second rotation to the second vector only, about an axis that passes through its rotated origin (from the first rotation)

Comment: This is actually what I do exactly. I apply the the first rotation to both vectors (z axis), afterwards to the second vector only (to the y axis). But since after the first rotation the x and y axes are somewhere else, depending how much I rotate on the z axis, the second rotation does not work correctly.  Please see the image for the shift of axes after a rotation [link](https://images1.programmerall.com/130/fc/fc2258aae9d5e450e5499495d9a47fd2.png)

Comment: Can you include in your question the piece of code that calls this function?  Actually I need the whole sequence of calls.

Comment: Please see my edit on the question.

Comment: I noticed a strange thing in your code.  You rotating by an angle that is expressed in degrees when you need to specify the angle in radians, right ?

Comment: Correct. I give the angles in degree for the rotation. Before the rotation, in `rotate_line()` function it is converted to radians.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132878/discussion-between-hosam-hajjir-and-mystic-06).

Comment: @mystic.06 Please check my updated solution.